# How to check the influence of 'pseudo-replication'?

Tags: random-generation

I am analyzing a certain hormone metabolites from the populations of free-ranging animals. The total samples (N) that I have collected, have a few repetitive samples from some individuals. Will these samples influence the result? What statistical tool should be used to check the influence of such samples?

Answer (score 1):

There may be an effect. It is possibly a small effect. It may be detectable, or maybe not. Try processing your data with and without repeats included and look at it. Try doing a time difference plot on the repeats and see if that shows anything significant. That is, for single repeats, (discarding studies beyond two per animal) plot difference in hormone metabolite(s) on the y-axis for difference in time on the x-axis. If there is no significant correlation, then it will be hard to tease out an effect. However, that doesn't rule out an effect in an absolute sense.

Comment: Thank you.  I did an autocorrelation test. I found that these values are not correlated to each other. I have collected the maximum of 3 samples from the same animal. But all samples are from different ecological timings. And each hold meaningful messages.